# Not able to push code to gitlab getting error "GitLab: API is not accessible"

Tags: git, gitlab

Please find below error

`remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
To http://git.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.xxxx.com/xxxx/xxxxx.git'`

Comment: Is this a new installation or did it just appear out of the blue?

Answer (score 1):

That could be a right issue associated with your GitLab profile.
See for instance [issue 40](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/40):

> They change something in 7.4:

```
gitlab default branch protected
```

> I have the same problem. A lot of developers here in my company working on the default branch and only have the developer role

Read more at "[Keeping your code protected](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)"

You can also `Open your project > Settings` and go to "`Protected branches`", select: "`Developers can push`" and try again.